# values of dict change when i pass it to function when they shouldn't

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

Learning python lately, I have a program which takes a list of dicts, (each dict in the list has keys repeated from the other dicts) .

it then passes it to a function whose job it is to aggregate the data in the values and return a single dict, however when I go to access the original dict again after the function call, it has been updated with the values from the single dict, I cannot see any part of the code in my method which is doing it, and have been stuck on it a few hours.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ast

def process_visitor_stats_list(original_list): 
    temp_original_list = original_list[:]  # attempt to copy original list so it doesnt get changed

    new_dict = {}   # this will store each unique key in dict along with the sum of its values
    for line in temp_original_list:  
        for key in line:
            if(key not in new_dict):  # checks if key is in new_dict, adds it if not and adds a value which tracks how often the key occurs
                new_dict[key] = line[key]
                new_dict[key].append(1)    # it also adds another number to the value, which stores the amount of times it was in the original list of dicts

            else:
                new_dict[key][0] += float(line[key][0])  # if key is already in dict, it sums its values 
                new_dict[key][1] += float(line[key][1])   
                new_dict[key][2] += 1 

    return new_dict


if __name__ == "__main__":

    original_list_of_dicts = []  # this will store my list of dicts

    line1 = "{'entry1': [4.0, 2.0], 'entry2': [592.0, 40.0], 'entry3': [5247044.0, 1093776.0], 'entry4': [1235.0, 82.0]}"
    line2 = "{'entry1': [26260.0, 8262.0], 'entry2': [2.0, 0.0], 'entry3': [1207.0, 142.0], 'entry4': [382992.0, 67362.0]}"
    line3 = "{'entry1': [57486.0, 16199.0], 'entry2': [6.0, 3.0], 'entry3': [280.0, 16.0]}"

    original_list_of_dicts.append(ast.literal_eval(line1))  # adds each line to the list and casts them as dicts
    original_list_of_dicts.append(ast.literal_eval(line2))
    original_list_of_dicts.append(ast.literal_eval(line3))

    print "original list of dicts before method call"
    for line in original_list_of_dicts:    # prints out each entry in the list of dicts
        for key in line:
            print key + str(line[key])

    print '\n'
    new_dict = process_visitor_stats_list(original_list_of_dicts)    # calls the method to process the original list of dicts
    print '\n'                                                      # this should return a single dict list with aggregate data


    print "original list of dicts after method call"
    for line in original_list_of_dicts:   # however when i go to access the original dict, its values have been changed
        for key in line:
            print key + str(line[key])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy the list:

```
temp_original_list = original_list[:]
```

you only do a *shallow* copy, i.e. the new list contains references to the same objects that were in the original list. As the objects within the list are mutable dictionaries, you will need to do a *deep* copy of the list:

```
import copy

temp_original_list = copy.deepcopy(original_list)
```

This will recursively copy the objects within containers and create new versions of those, too.

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

---

Strictly speaking, your problem isn't related as much to the dictionaries as to the lists they hold in turn (e.g. `original_list[0]['entry1']`). On this line:

```
new_dict[key] = line[key]
```

you are referencing the *same list object* in `new_dict` as was in `original_list`. Therefore when you mutate it, e.g.:

```
new_dict[key].append(1)
```

this change also appears in the original dictionary. You could therefore also have solved this by making the inner list a copy (only shallow copy required here, as it contains immutable values rather than mutable containers):

```
new_dict[key] = line[key][:]
```

Comment: that's great thanks it's fixed my problem, I'm still not sure how the original dict values were being changed though

Comment: I have added to my answer - does that help?